# Top 2 box (T2B) margin of error calculation. Where's the mistake?

Tags: confidence-interval, error, frequentist

I have a survey asking customers to rate their satisfaction on 1-5 scale.

I'm interested in learning the margin of error for a *derived* quantity, namely the "top2box%", i.e. the percentage of respondents who gave a $4$ *or* a $5$.

How would I go about calculating this? If treated like a simple multiple choice, I'd have (let's say 95% CI)

$$MOE=z_{0.95} \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} * FPC$$

and take $p=0.5$ for the largest margin, so that
$$MOE = \frac{0.98}{\sqrt{n}}*FPC$$

But I think a correction has to be made for the fact that I'm grouping $4$ and $5$ together, so it can't quite be treated like a single percentage?

From what I found, the margin of error should increase for the T2B approach... but if I calculate the variance of %(4 or 5), it's the same formula as variance of %(any choice), namely $p(1-p)$?

So I'm getting the same answer as here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error , despite this being top2 box, which is supposed to have a larger MOE supposedly.

Where's the mistake?

Comment: Recode 4 and 5 as "1" and everything else as "0".  Proceed as with any binary variable.

Comment: @whuber that's what I did and got this result which seems off

Comment: One what basis does it "seem off"?

Comment: @whuber like I wrote, I'm getting the same result as if I just considered a binary variable.

But according to this, top2 box results in wider error bars ,and loss of information https://measuringu.com/top-box-behavior/

Comment: I was unable to see how your reference specifies anything different than what I described.  The "loss of information" would be relative to some (unspecified) other procedure based on all five values -- but that's not what you're asking about.